# JavaScript boolean if statement problems

Tags: javascript

I have a button that, when clicked, makes an alert window pop up. When the button is clicked, a variable called "master" changes from false to true. Then, I have an if statement that checks if the variable is true. If it is, then it alerts the value of the variable. Here's the problem: the last part isn't happening. It's like the if statement isn't executing, then it stops the rest of the program. I did check to see if the "master" variable is registering as true, and it is, so I don't really know what's wrong.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>Tic-Tac-Toe Game</title>
                <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

                <!-- Optional theme -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
                <style type="text/css">
                    #buttons{
                        margin-top: 50px;
                    }
                    #x{
                        margin-left: 10px;
                    }
                    #table{
                        margin-top: 15px;
                        background: gray;
                        table-layout: fixed;
                        width: auto;
                        width: 250px;
                        height: 250px;


                    }


                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="container" id="buttons">    
                    <h2 id = "h2" >Choose your team!</h2>
                    <button onclick = "myFunctions()" type = "button" class="btn btn-default"><span style = "font-weight: bold; font-size: 110%;">O</span></button>
                    <button type = "button" id = "x" class="btn btn-default"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>

                    <table id = "table" class="table table-bordered">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td id = "td" onclick="myFunction()"></td>
                                <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
                                <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
                                <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
                                <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
                                <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
                                <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>


                </div>


                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var master = false;
                    var servant = false;
                    function myFunction(){
                        alert('hi');
                    }

                    function myFunctions(){
                        master = true;
                    }

                    if (master == true) {
                        alert(master);
                    }

                </script>

                <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
                <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Please choose better names for your functions. This is a great part of your issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Refer the corrected code below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Tic-Tac-Toe Game</title>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            #buttons{
                margin-top: 50px;
            }
            #x{
                margin-left: 10px;
            }
            #table{
                margin-top: 15px;
                background: gray;
                table-layout: fixed;
                width: auto;
                width: 250px;
                height: 250px;


            }


        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" id="buttons">    
            <h2 id = "h2" >Choose your team!</h2>
            <button onclick = "myFunctions()" type = "button" class="btn btn-default"><span style = "font-weight: bold; font-size: 110%;">O</span></button>
            <button type = "button" id = "x" class="btn btn-default"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>

            <table id = "table" class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td id = "td" onclick="myFunction()"></td>
                        <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
                        <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
                        <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
                        <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
                        <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
                        <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>


        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            var master = false;
            var servant = false;
            function myFunction(){
                alert('hi');
               master = true;
            if (master == true) {
                alert(master);
            }
           }
        </script>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

> Reason is was not executing is you had function called as myFunctions but actually you were calling `myFunction()` for `onclick` event

Answer (score 0):

First you set master to false, then you declare two functions: 'myFunction' and 'myFunctions', then you check if master == true. As master is false, so you won't see the alert.

When you click the buttons, only the function myFunction or myFunctions gets executed. The test 'master == true' does not get executed again, it is not part of the functions